# Can Access to an Html element without document.getElementById()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i wrote a sample Html page that contain a img and change src of img with code

```
<img id='p6'/>

document.getElementById('p6').src='somting.jpg';
```

when i write code in  tag find that i can write this code instead of above code:

```
p6.src='somting.jpg';
```

and it work perfectly...can anyone say to me what happend in this code? and realy we can access Html element whitout use document.getElementById() ?

Comment: why would anyone upvote this?

Comment: its all explained here: http://bit.ly/1QlBHFH

Comment: i dont define p6 variable Paranav!

Comment: important to note that you do not rely on it, at all, ever

Comment: i dont know why upvote thus question :)

Comment: @Alex someone who knows how confusing programming may be at start and how hard it is to find answers when you don't know the questions might upvote this, not to promote the question, but to balance the votes, knowing OP will not be able to post any other questions soon due to bad votes. ( wasn't me who upvoted tho)

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin this "question" doesnt really have a question plus it lacks 100% basic knowledge

Comment: Yes we can, as long the element has an id but it's depricated; don't do it :)

Comment: whye do not relay on it Jaromanda X? it work in all browser

Comment: Hans Gerber ..can you give a refrence for your comment?

Comment: @HansGerber That's not deprecated feature, that's even being standardized in HTML5 spec but doesn't mean it should be used in any case  http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object

Comment: becuase my code run only on chrome browser i think i can use it

Comment: @A. Wolff Ah ok. I remembered it wrong. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
p6.src='somting.jpg';
```

`p6` is a reference var to the actual dom node with id of `p6`, something like:

```
var p6 = document.getElementById('p6');
    p6.src='somting.jpg'; // now on you can use p6 as a ref. to the img
```

---

You can also use it when you create dynamic dom nodes:

```js
var p6 = document.createElement('img');
    p6.id = "p6";
    p6.src = "some/path/to/img.ext";

    document.body.appendChild(p6);
```

Comment: and realy dont use var document.getElementById('p6')?

Comment: can you create a demo where you see it working without defining?

Comment: in create dynamic dom is ok and becuase we define p6 before can access it but access all element without document.getElementById is Interesting and useful

Comment: @combo_ci If you have this var in any js file go and find the var.

Answer (score 0):

if you use the jQuery library, you can put :

```
$("#p6").attr('src', 'somting.jpg')
```